# How to make a n-dimention list with one dimention lists with a loop

Tags: python, list, split

I'm learning python and I have been trying to make an automatic list of lists. For example:

The next list, which I have to split to get a list of separated letters, and then join them again to make a two lists of separated letters

```
lists=[['a,b,c,h'],['d,e,f,g']]

print('list length', len(lists))
splited=[]

splited1=lists[0][0].split(',')
print(splited1)  #['a', 'b', 'c', 'h']

splited2=lists[1][0].split(',')
print(splited2)  #['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']


listcomb=[splited1,splited2]

print(listcomb) #[['a', 'b', 'c', 'h'], ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']]
```

This is what I want to get, a list that have 2 lists, but in the case I have to get more lists inside that list i want to make it automatic with a for loop.

My try, but it didn't work

```
listcomb2=zip(splited1,splited2)
print(listcomb2)

sepcomb = list()
print(type(sepcomb))
for x in range(len(lists)):
    sep=lists[x][0].split(',')
    sepcomb[x]=[sep]
print(sepcomb)
```

I'm having problems with splitting the letters and then joining them in a new list. Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make some tweak in your code. As we can see lenght of `sepcomb` is `0` so use `append` method to avoid this problem. As `sepcomb[x]=[sep]` is is assignment to `x-index` but it `x index` doesn't exist so, it will raise error

**change:**

```
for x in range(len(lists)):
    sep=lists[x][0].split(',')
    sepcomb[x]=[sep]
```

**to**

```
for x in range(len(lists)):
    sep=lists[x][0].split(',')
    sepcomb.append(sep)
```

**Method-2**

```
sepcomb = list(i[0].split(',') for i in lists)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's just what I was looking for, I'm new in python and I always get confused when using .append

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do  the following:

```
final=[splinted1]+[splinted2]
```

Or a better way directly from the `lists` variable would be:

```
final=[value[0].split(',') for value in lists]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Here you go:

```py
lists = [['a,b,c,h'],['d,e,f,g']]

listcomb = []
for each in lists:
    splited = each[0].split(',')
    listcomb.append(splited)
print(listcomb)
```